# get the width and height of my device and inject them into my css style

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to programmatically find the device-width in Phonegap/JQuery mobile and inject them into my css style with a modification.

Here is the css code that i am trying to change the height of the element "wrapper" according to the device's height as well the width

```
#wrapper {
    width: 310px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: relative; /* On older OS versions "position" and "z-index" must be defined, */
    z-index: 1; /* it seems that recent webkit is less picky and works anyway. */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Can anyone have an idea how it work? thanks

Comment: please give 100% width and height

Comment: thanks but i really need to work with pixels

Comment: may be use one of the js below and inject the css to your header? like this http://learn.jquery.com/performance/use-stylesheets-for-changing-css/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // This will execute whenever the window is resized
  $(window).height(); // New height
  $(window).width(); // New width
});
```

Comment: well all i want to do is a scroller with a 3500px width and every wrapper is getting 310px of the entire width but the problem is that it works on one device perfectly but i need to get this work on multiple devices so that why i can work only with pixels

Comment: did you try to get height and width from tag

Answer (score 0):

Call Event in $(document).ready(function()

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);
```

Here is Function:

```
function resizeFrame() {
var newHeight = $(window).height();
var newWidth = $(window).width();

$('#wrapper').width(newWidth);
$('#wrapper').height(newHeight);
}
```